# Adding device display options on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am making a website for selling web templates. On a demo pages of templates, I would like to have an option to test how the website looks on different types of screens. Like in this example https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/tacos-hotels-restaurants-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/

Any advice how to make this?

Thanks in advance!
Denis

Comment: Simply dive into the linked code and check how they did it

Comment: I think  you should preview the template inside an iframe, then resize the iframe by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'Live Preview/Demo' button to the overview page of your theme.

When the user clicks this 'Live Preview' button, the user is directed to the page displaying your full themed website **with an appended div (iframe) at the top, that has two buttons.**

1. Option to buy the theme now
2. Remove the Frame

[ThemeForest](https://themeforest.net) is a great example of this technique.